# What does Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| ... end exactly do, in terms of ruby codes?

Tags: ruby, vagrant

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| end
```

ruby codes lookes like

```
(0..5).each do |i| ... end
```

So

```
(0..5).each do |i|
    puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

It loops through 0 to 5, assign each item to i and then the codes within the "do ... end" would do something with the i.

Now let's see

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| end.
```

Does it mean?

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION)
```

is similar as

```
(0..5).each
```

- loop through something (and what it loops through?)
- return each item in the loop, assign each item to "config"
- and then the codes within "do |config| ... end" will do something about the item "config"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks are not tied to looping. It is just a closure. When a method calls `yield`, the block that was passed is called. After the block is executed, the original method continues.

```
def understanding_blocks
  puts 1
  puts yield
  puts 3
end
```

If you ran:

```
understanding_blocks do
  2
end
```

You will see

```
1 
2 
3
```

In Ruby, all methods can implicitly take a block, which is why I did not have to define an argument. I could have though. You can test if a block was given to a method by using `block_given?`

Comment: So Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) is a method and it takes the the do .. end block as a parameter?

Comment: Just like the (0..5).each is a iterator method that takes a block as a parameter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It passes an empty block to whatever `Vagrant.configure` does. There is no effect, and it could be omitted, and should be since it's redundant:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION)
```